# How to send NSData as parameter in POST method swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, nsurlsession

I'm trying to send a PDF file's `NSData` to server as a parameter in `POST` method, by converting PDF into `NSData` and then `NSData` to `String`,

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let getPDFPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("resume.pdf")
let pdfdata = NSData(contentsOfFile: getPDFPath) 
let dataString: String? = "\(pdfdata!)"
```

And uploading as parameter using `NSURLSession` like this,

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://someurl/pdf.aspx")!)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 let postString = "pdfdata=\(dataString!)"
 request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return }
                 if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                 print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                 print("response = \(response)")
                }
 let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
 task.resume()
```

But it's always giving me Error :

```
 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was
 lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8d63f34250 {Error
 Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)"
 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
 NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://someurl/pdf.aspx,
 NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://someurl/pdf.aspx,
 _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
```

Things i have tried:

1. Restarting Simulator
2. Reset All settings of Simulator
3. Same error with Alamofire
4. Tried different Simulators
5. App Transport Security is YES in `info.plist`
6. Only one PDF file (which is 21kb) gets uploaded, others not

Comment: The error message says your connection was lost. Are you sure you have a working Internet connection?

Comment: Yes, pdf downloading happens perfectly fine on the same network.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your App Transport Security settings don't allow you to go to the specified URL.
Insert this in your app's plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Hi, i did that also, forgot to add it in question, edited question now. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS9 you are required to use https only for security reasons. You may edit the Info.plist file and add an exception for your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Read more about App Transport Security here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: I just tried it, it still not working, but small pdf  (20kb) uploaded, but large (100kb) didn't

Comment: Did you activate the Sandbox in your project settings in Xcode?

Comment: No, i didn't , its all turned off

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the the project type you chose in Xcode? Some project types may require you to activate the Sandbox. For example when you write an app extension. Try activating the the sandbox feature and activate "Outgoing Connections(Client)".

Comment: I'm using xcode 7.3.1 and i chose it to be iPhone application in Swift, with Pods installed, i'll try sandbox thing now

Comment: Yes, i tried but it didn't work :( Thanks for helping again